# How can I generate an exponential signal in simulation software?

Tags: signal, simulation, multisim, function-generator

In Multisim, I can generate a few signals using the function generator like sine wave, triangular wave, square wave.

Can I generate a signal like \$i(t)= 2e^{50t}\$ in Multisim software or any other simulation software?

Comment: Remember that \$e^{50t} = 148\ \text{amperes}\$ when \$t = 100\ \text{ms}\$. So you would be able to simulate only a few seconds before some variable overflows.

Answer (score 4):

In spice you have *behavioral current sources (bi)*.

[image]